# Is there any way to change password with out the old password and email verification in dotnet core with identity framework

Tags: .net-core, web-applications, identity

Admin needs to reset the password without the old password and email verification.Is there any way to achieve this in dot net core web app using the identity package.Requirement is for a local area network web app not connected to internet. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync() + UserManager.AddPasswordAsync().

You should also validate the new password before using the UserManager.PasswordValidators to make sure that the user doesn't end up with no password (if UserManager.AddPasswordAsync() failes).

Another solution is to create a password reset token with UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync() and then set the new password using that token with UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync().